# Setting outFiles in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I set outfiles in Visual Studio Code? I am told this is required to speed up the Chrome Debugger. At present it takes the debugger about 3-5 minutes of just hanging there to when VSCode actually stops on the breakpoint.

I have js files in several folders in my root directory where `index.html` resides. The folders in the root directory include: `General`, `MyProject`, ... etc

This is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to enable sourcemaps and add an `outFiles` section to that `launch.json`. Checkout the `outFiles` section of the [pwa-chrome](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) config options. And the [node sourcemaps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps) info.